# Locate mysql on cluster using console

Tags: mysql, hadoop, ambari, cloudera-manager

How to locate where mysql server is installed in which node of the cluster using console(w/o using any UI such as Ambari and Cloudera Manager).

Answer (score 0):

If the SSH is setup in your cluster, then using the below shell script, you can find the server on which MySQL is installed:

```
ssh user_name@host_name mysql --version
ssh user_name@other_host_name mysql --version
```